# Computing the summation of distinct primes of $n$?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

### Background

I recently had the following idea. We define $k(n)$ as the product of the first $n$ primes where $p_n$ is the $n$'th prime.

$$k(n) = \prod_{i=1}^n p_i$$

For example, $k(2) = 2 \cdot 3 = 6$. We write $n$'th integer as:

$$ n = \underbrace{1+ 1+ \dots}_{n \text{ terms}}$$

Inserting $n(n-1)$ terms of $0$'s into series, which will repeat as:

$$ n = \underbrace{0+ 0+ \dots + 0 +1}_{n^2 \text{ terms}}$$

Now consider, the expansion of $p_n \lambda_n$ as an example:

$$ 2 \lambda_1 = \underbrace{0+1+0+1 + \dots}_{2^2 \lambda_1 \text{ terms}}   $$

$$ 3 \lambda_2 = \underbrace{0+0+1+0+0+1 +0+0+1+ \dots}_{3^2 \lambda_2 \text{ terms}} $$

$$ 5 \lambda_3 = \underbrace{0+0+0+0+1+0+0+0+0+1+ \dots}_{5^2 \lambda_3 \text{ terms}} $$

Now, we choose $\lambda_1$,  $\lambda_2$, $\dots$, $\lambda_n$. Such that:

$$ 2^2 \lambda_1 = 3^2 \lambda_2 = 5^2 \lambda_3 = k(3)^2$$

Hence, when we add $2\lambda_1$, $3\lambda_2$, $5 \lambda_3$ together to get:

$$k(3)^2 (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5})= \sum_{r=1}^{k(3)^2}\sum_{5 \geq p_i} \omega_{p_i}(r)$$

where we vertically add for the R.H.S with $\omega_{p_i}(n)$ being the number of distinct primes of $p_i$ in $n$.  Hence, in general:

$$ k(n)^2 (\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{p_r}) = \sum_{r=1}^{k(n)^2} \sum_{p_n \geq p_i} \omega_{p_i}(r) $$

### Question

Is the formula valid in the limit $n \to \infty$

$$ k(n)^2 (\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{p_r}) \sim \sum_{r=1}^{k(n)^2}  \omega(r) $$

where $\omega(r)$ is then number of distinct primes of $r$?

Comment: The notation is not clear. What is "the expansion" of $p_n\lambda_n$? What is $k$? What is $\omega_{p_i}$?

Comment: $k(n)$ is a function which is the product of the first $n$ primes. So $k(3) = 2.3.5 = 30$. $\omega_{p_i} (n) $ is a function which is the number of distinct primes of $p_i$ so $\omega_{p_1}(8) = 3$ where $p_1$ is $2$.

Comment: The expansion refers to writing an integer as follows $2 = 0+1+0+1$. Now multiplying $\lambda_1$  (and let us choose  $\lambda_1 =3 $ for connivence) then  $2 \cdot 3 = 0+1+0+1+0+1+0+1+0+1+0+1 $

Comment: @GregMartin I hope this clarifies things?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, the question could have been asked without the first 80% of the post—that would have made it easier for potential helpers to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are asking is equivalent to this statement. Given $x>2$, define $K=\prod_{p\le x} p$ and $R=\sum_{p\le x} \frac1p$ (where both sums are over primes only). You are asking whether $K^2R \sim \sum_{r=1}^{K^2} \omega(r)$.

By standard results, $R\sim \log\log x$, while $\sum_{r=1}^{K^2} \omega(r) \sim K^2\log\log(K^2) \sim K^2\log\log K$. Since $\log K = \theta(x) \sim x$, we have $K^2R \sim K^2\log\log x$ while $\sum_{r=1}^{K^2} \omega(r) \sim K^2\log x$; thus the two are not asymptotic.